# Load data from URL to slow

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, uiscrollview

I have a uicollectionView and when i select a cell a new view is load.The content is the image which was selected from collection view and i can scroll between images.

I did this but it's takes too much time to load the image selected.

This is how i did :

```
- (void)passDataForward
{
    PageViewController *secondViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"page"];

    secondViewController.data =tagsender;
    secondViewController.imageArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:imagesArray copyItems:YES];
    secondViewController.delegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:secondViewController animated:YES completion:^(void)
     {

     }];
}
```

in imagesArray i have url for images.

In my new viewController :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    for (int i = 0; i < [imageArray count]; i++) {

        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i+100;
        frame.origin.y = 100;
        frame.size = CGSizeMake(110.0, 120.0);
                UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

               dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                                                     [NSURL URLWithString:[imageArray objectAtIndex:i]]]];
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                imageView.image=image;
                });
        });


       [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];

    }
```

Comment: Well how big is the images?

Comment: Well what would you like us to do about it then? If you are downloading a very big image of course it will take a while to download. Maybe decrease the size of the image by decreasing the resolution of it or actual size (width and height) or pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Load data maybe slow for many reasons. The code that you have included seems to be correct. In any case, you can use third party library such as [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) that supports great features to fetch remote images.

Comment: Yes he is right, SDWebImage is a very good third party API which caches the Image data and furthur wont fire the URL if it was fired and the code was broken. and you can even set the number of days it will keep the cache.